# Cucumber execution stops for execution if initial @then fails for Automation

Tags: java, automation, cucumber

I'm using cucumber framework for the testing. I've three @then conditions, if 1st @then condition gets failed, its not going into second @then condition. How can I overcome?

```
   @Then("^I check first result$")
public void verifyFirstResult() {
    Assert.assertEquals(results.get("first"), true);    --> This gets failed as its returning false.    
}


@Then("^I check second result$")
public void verifySecondResult() {
    Assert.assertEquals(results.get("second"), true);  --> This is not even triggering, the execution stops at the first method itself 
}


 @Then("^I check third result$")
public void verifyThirdResult() {
    Assert.assertEquals(results.get("third"), true);  
}
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As the steps are written, you cannot overcome this issue. This is how cucumber works. If a step fails, all subsequent steps are skipped until the end of the scenario.

If you want to check multiple conditions in one `Then` step, you can create a "compound" step that checks multiple conditions, which will cause this one step to fail. This is usually done with a data table:

```
Then the results should be:
    | Field  | Value |
    | First  | true  |
    | Second | true  |
    | Third  | true  |
```

References:

- https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#data-tables
- https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/step-definitions/

Comment: Thanks. But those docs doesn't provide any snippets.can you pls post one snippet

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify the question better?
1) Are you trying to check the three conditions simultaneously, so that the test will fail if any of them (no matter which one) fails?
2) Or are you interested in knowing which particular condition failed in case of error?